# What type of touch button is this?

Tags: button, touch

There's a touch button which has a spring on the PCB.

- Is it capacitive?
- How does it work?
- Do I need a special circuit to read touch events?

[image]

Comment: who knows? Might just be there for springiness reasons, and the switch is optical. Or, this might be an antenna and measuring coupling. Or, this might just be a capacitive element, excited at a frequency low enough that the coiledness makes no difference... as usual, a lot more information about the device your looking at, the missing parts of that button, etc might be useful!

Comment: No, i'm sure this is a button and the pad which is connected to spring's end goes to a uC or a circuit.

Comment: still missing the rest of the button. vtc as lacking necessary detail.

Comment: There's a circular trace on the pcb. The pad on this trace connected to spring's end. LEDs are irrelevant in the middle.

Comment: What board is this from? And what is the button connected to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a capacitive touch sensing. This is used in many electric stove as its accuracy is high and it can come in direct contact of the surface need to be touched by the user.

Yes, you need a special IC which can read the events as, when someone touches the switch of comes very close, tiny current flows through it. It needs to be detected and event to be generated.Specific IC is available for this purpose.

Comment: How is it different from other capacitive touch sensor like pcb type ones? Because there's an extra spring element on the pcb. It means cost and area.

Comment: see the image "https://www.edn.com/wp-content/uploads/media-1126449-266540-6643877-fig11.gif" when w have to put LCD and button on the same box so that the height of the screen may create a problem, then we use. Yes, it will be costly but the requirement is such.

Comment: No special IC is needed. Many MCUs have hardware peripherals to assist in capacitive sensing, or the MCU can do it in software, and usually the MCU manufacturer provides a touch sensing library to hide the capacitive touch sensing algorithms from the user so it will just work.

Comment: @Deepak Which IC or uC used for the circuit in the photo?

Comment: @BerkerIşık use MTCH101, read datasheet "http://pdl.designspark.com/api/v1/manufacturers/53f34c609b4759f869f43134/part/53f355779b4759f8690734b2/548f24469b475962668b7f25/1pdf" it suits your application

Answer (score 1):

It’s hard to read the schematic from a photo, but I see an optical detector and SMD LED so I suspect it is an optical reflective switch with optical indicator using pulse mode detection.  You can ohm out the circuit to create a schematic and make closer pictures on both sides of PCB. use a flash and get it in focus.

Comment: No, middle LED is irrelevant. I'm sure it is a touch switch.

Comment: Then please define the components better or show better pictures

Comment: yes, you keep claiming that, but all points to this not being what you claim it to be. This could easily be solved by adding a photo of the missing button cap / whatever goes on top of the spring, but you refuse to add that, @BerkerIşık. That's why I voted to close.

Comment: I don't refuse, @MarcusMüller. I don't have the button cap part. Person i bought it said it was a touch switch and that's all i keep claiming and it's true. You can judge as you wish!. I'm just trying to find and understand the correct answer. I just said it is not optical and it does not contain any other components. Please let go of prejudice!

Comment: cool, so why don't you edit your question to include that info? And information about what that device actually is?

Comment: @BerkerIşık  I can hardly see the silkscreen or parts in photo, but again I think you could be wrong. they start with D for diode (emitter or detector)  This makes an excellent touch detector with near-field reflections blocked by cylinder that gives tactile feel with spring